# How can I pass an istream to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arguments

EDIT: I changed multiple parts of code in one commit without realizing it, resulting in much of the confusion in the comments.

Now I can see what the question should be: how can I pass an istream to a function in c++?

Example:

```
int ncharf()
{
    char neww;
    myfile.get(neww);
    return (int)neww;
}
```

Where myfile is an istream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass `myfile` as an argument.

```
int ncharf(istream &myfile)
{
    char neww;
    myfile.get(neww);
    return (int)neww;
}
```

Also, as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) commented: [The argument to .get() must be of type **char**, not **int**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

If you want to read an int from a binary file you should use [`istream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) instead:

```
int ncharf(istream &myfile)
{
    int neww;
    myfile.read((char*)&neww, sizeof(int));
    return neww;
}
```

Comment: There is a possibility that `myfile` is a global variable and doesn't need passing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Look at the error message the OP got. It's complaining that `.get` isn't being applied to a class object.

Comment: If I want to read an int from a file in binary mode, I need to specify *the size of the int* in the `get` method, otherwise it reads a single character.  For example: `myfile.get((char *) &new, sizeof(int))`.

Comment: `get()` reads char and c-strings not int, it will stop reading if it encounters a delimiting character ('\n' by default).